# Converting to date in PHP from yyyymmdd format

Tags: php, datetime, date, format

I have dates in the following format (yyyymmdd, 18751104, 19140722)... what's the easiest way to convert it to date().... or is using mktime() and substrings my best option...?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use [`strtotime()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to convert a string containing a date into a [Unix timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time):

```
<?php
// both lines output 813470400
echo strtotime("19951012"), "\n",
     strtotime("12 October 1995");
?>
```

You can pass the result as the second parameter to [`date()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to reformat the date yourself:

```
<?php
// prints 1995 Oct 12
echo date("Y M d", strtotime("19951012"));
?>
```

##Note
`strtotime()` will fail with dates before the Unix epoch at the start of 1970.

As an alternative which will work with dates before 1970:

```
<?php
// Returns the year as an offset since 1900, negative for years before
$parts = strptime("18951012", "%Y%m%d");
$year = $parts['tm_year'] + 1900; // 1895
$day = $parts['tm_mday']; // 12
$month = $parts['tm_mon']; // 10
?>
```

Comment: @Serhiy strtotime() returns false for dates before 1970, so in essence you're calling date(0), which will return Dec 31st 23:59:59 1969

Comment: $month actually returns "9", not "10", since srtptime gives months as "Months since January (0-11)". So you need $parts['tm_mon']+1 to get to "10".

Answer (score 9):

Personally, I'd just use substr() because it's probably the lightest way to do it anyway.

But here's a function that takes a date, of which you can specify the format. It returns an associative array, so you could do for example (untested):

```
$parsed_date = date_parse_from_format('Ymd', $date);
$timestamp = mktime($parsed_date['year'], $parsed_date['month'], $parsed_date['day']);
```

http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php

Although I must say, I don't find that any easier or more effective than simply:

```
mktime(substr($date, 0, 4), substr($date, 4, 2), substr($date, 6, 2));
```

Comment: I had voted for this as the answer... but mktime suffers from the same 1970 problem as the other answer... and that arrangement for mktime is a bit off...

Answer (score 4):

(PHP 5 >= 5.3.0, PHP 7):

You can get a DateTime instance with:

```
$dateTime = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd|', '18951012');
```

and convert it to a timestamp:

```
$timestamp = $dateTime->getTimestamp();
// -> -2342217600
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`strptime`](http://php.net/strptime). It can parse a time/date generated with `strftime`.

Example from the docs:

> ```php
> <?php
> $format = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'; $strf = strftime($format);
>
> echo "$strf\n";
>
> print_r(strptime($strf, $format));
> ?>
> ```
>
> The above example will output something similar to:
>
> ```php
> 03/10/2004 15:54:19
>
> Array (
>     [tm_sec] => 19
>     [tm_min] => 54
>     [tm_hour] => 15
>     [tm_mday] => 3
>     [tm_mon] => 9
>     [tm_year] => 104
>     [tm_wday] => 0
>     [tm_yday] => 276
>     [unparsed] =>
> )
> ```

Comment: @mickmackusa: thanks, I've updated my answer from back in the days (phew, almost 10 years old!)

Comment: You are one of cooperative 1% that actually improves content after becoming aware.  Thank you for improving Stack Overflow.  It would have been better if you would have tailored the snippet to deal specifically with the OP's provided format. (`Ymd`)

Answer (score 0):

Well thanks for all the answers but the 1900 problem seems to plague every response I got. Here is a copy of the function I am using should someone find it useful for them in the future.

```
public static function nice_date($d){
    $ms = array(
           'January',
           'February',
           'March',
           'April',
           'May',
           'June',
           'July',
           'August',
           'September',
           'October',
           'November',
           'December'
    );

    $the_return = '';
    $the_month = abs(substr($d,4,2));
    if ($the_month != 0) {
        $the_return .= $ms[$the_month-1];
    }

    $the_day = abs(substr($d,6,2));
    if ($the_day != 0){
        $the_return .= ' '.$the_day;
    }

    $the_year = substr($d,0,4);
    if ($the_year != 0){
        if ($the_return != '') {
            $the_return .= ', ';
        }
        $the_return .= $the_year;
    }

    return $the_return;
}
```